# Return the wrong type in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class Color that contains three float components (r, g, b).

I have to program the following function :

Color getColor(unsigned char values[], int i)

Normally I should program it like this :

```
Color getColor(unsigned char values[], int i){
     return Color((float) values[i]/255.0, (float) values[i+1]/255.0, (float) values[i+2]/255.0);
}
```

But by error I did

```
return values[i];
```

When I compiled I didn't get any compilation error and I haven't get run time error either.

Why this is possible?

Comment: You´re calling Color with a constructor with 3 unsigned chars. Does it have a constructor with 1 unsigned char too? ... Then it´s implicitely constructed with it.

Comment: Are there any constructors for `Color` that take a single argument? What happens if you declare them as `explicit`?

Comment: Please show how the Color class/struct is defined.

Comment: Ok thanks I didn't know that in C++ we can do that. Yes I have a constructor that take one component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a result of non-explicit constructor of Color class accepting unsigned char as its argument.

That means you have constructor in Color class with single argument OR multiple arguments rest being default parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check your constructor in the `Color` class and overwrite with the required one.